# ClientError: Unable to parse csv K-means in SageMarker

Tags: aws, amazon-s3

Estoy intentando ejecutar el algoritmo K-means en SageMaker de AWS. Tengo mi archivo .csv subido a S3 y he creado mi 'training job':

[image]

Y obtengo el siguiente error: "ClientError: Unable to parse csv: rows 1-5000, file /opt/ml/input/data/train/myFile.csv"

He visto varios foros con problemas similares, pero eliminar la cabecera o probar con menos datos me sigue sin funcionar.

¿Alguna idea?

Gracias.

Comment: Usa RecordIO en lugar de CSV